# How to get Cookies with HttpURLConnection in Java?

Tags: java, cookies, httpurlconnection

When I use `HttpURLConnection` and try `con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie")` I get this response:

```
__cfduid=1111111aaaaaa; expires=Wed, 19-Dec-18 06:19:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.site.com; HttpOnly
```

But the browser cookies are:

```
__cfduid=1111111aaaaaa; _ym_uid=000000000; PHPSESSID=zzzzzzzz; _ym_isad=1; key=555
```

How I can get the FULL cookie, using `HttpURLConnection`? The most important cookie for me is `key`.

Comment: Note, if con.getHeaderField(name) is called on a connection that sets the same header multiple times with possibly different values (which may be the case for 'set-cookie'), only the last value is returned. So better you iterate through all headers fields and test each field for the name 'Set-Cookie'.

Answer (score 7):

The value of `Set-cookie` header modify or append new value to Cookies in browser. And browser delete expired cookie from cookies. The assembling work completed by browser.

When request web in java, programmer need assemble 'full' cookies by `Set-cookie` header in single or multi responses.

If you use `HttpURLConnection`, you can use [CookieManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html)

This is an example

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com");

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.getContent();

List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
    System.out.println(cookie.getDomain());
    System.out.println(cookie);
}
```

When you send HTTP request, `CookieManager` will auto fill Cookie Header. And, the value can be directly achieved from `CookieManger` by domain.

Comment: And how to do it? Can a small example? We have one HeaderField("Set-Cookie"), and I need full cookies.

Comment: @Shannon the answer here shows how to set cookies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814462/how-to-get-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-by-using-cookiestore

Comment: did not work for me, but it did using the Apache HttpClient library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28973623/1915920