# How to get "Set-Cookie:" value?

Tags: java, get

I need the application to show me my current ip address.

In this case, we have something like this (Get request)

> [image]

I need to get ip from here

> [image]

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "http://2ip.ru/";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Cookies with HttpURLConnection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881165/how-to-get-cookies-with-httpurlconnection-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the answer to this question:
[How to get Cookies with HttpURLConnection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881165/how-to-get-cookies-with-httpurlconnection-in-java)

Or extract the cookies from the headers. Example ([Source](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/urlconnection/get-cookies-from-http-connection/)):

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class GetCookiesFromHTTPConnection {     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {         
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com:80");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();

        Set<String> headerFieldsSet = headerFields.keySet();
        Iterator<String> hearerFieldsIter = headerFieldsSet.iterator();

        while (hearerFieldsIter.hasNext()) {             
             String headerFieldKey = hearerFieldsIter.next();

             if ("Set-Cookie".equalsIgnoreCase(headerFieldKey)) {                  
                 List<String> headerFieldValue = headerFields.get(headerFieldKey);

                 for (String headerValue : headerFieldValue) {                      
                    System.out.println("Cookie Found...");

                    String[] fields = headerValue.split(";\s*");

                    String cookieValue = fields[0];
                    String expires = null;
                    String path = null;
                    String domain = null;
                    boolean secure = false;

                    // Parse each field
                    for (int j = 1; j < fields.length; j++) {
                        if ("secure".equalsIgnoreCase(fields[j])) {
                            secure = true;
                        }
                        else if (fields[j].indexOf('=') > 0) {
                            String[] f = fields[j].split("=");
                            if ("expires".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {
                                expires = f[1];
                            }
                            else if ("domain".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {
                                domain = f[1];
                            }
                            else if ("path".equalsIgnoreCase(f[0])) {
                                path = f[1];
                            }
                        }                         
                    }

                    System.out.println("cookieValue:" + cookieValue);
                    System.out.println("expires:" + expires);
                    System.out.println("path:" + path);
                    System.out.println("domain:" + domain);
                    System.out.println("secure:" + secure);

                    System.out.println("*****************************************");
                 }                  
             }             
        }         
    } 
}
```